# Get special character between text

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the "dot -> •" between the words (A-z) with this regex, but I also get the char before and after the dot:

```
/[A-z](•)[A-z]/g
```

here is the text:

```
1.•Molde•FK••••••••••••1•1•0•0•3:1•3•
2.•Ajax•Amsterdam••••••1•0•1•0•2:2•1•
•.•Celtic•Glasgow••••••1•0•1•0•2:2•1•
4.•Fenerbahce•Istanbul•1•0•0•1•1:3•0•
```

Comment: Your RegEx already [matches the dot](https://regex101.com/r/iU3eO3/1). You *are* using a single capturing group. Depending on your implementation, the matching function might return the entire string as first element, followed by the actual captures.

Comment: @dakab - yes but the chars get also removed. the "lookbehind" syntax is not working in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[A-z]` to `[A-Za-z]`. And get the string you want from group index 1.

```
/[a-z](•)[a-z]/gi
```

or

```
/[a-z](•)(?=[a-z])/gi
```

Comment: I am using jQuery as lang - the "lookbehind" syntax is not working for me with jQuery and ´/[a-z](•)[a-z]/gi´ also removes the last and first char of the words.

Comment: just fetch the dot from group index 1.

Comment: not bad but the char before the dot is still here --> https://regex101.com/r/mQ3dB2/1

Comment: @Mike ya, lookbehinds are not possible in js , so it always matches the previous character but you can get the captured character by the js lang itself.